# Trying to create Unity2D patrol script but enemy goes too fast regardless of what speed I set it to. It starts of slow and then goes too fast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a script where an enemy character moves between two set points. I found this code online:

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
if ( switching == false && PlayerInRange == false)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, PointA.position, PatrolSpeed);
}
else if (switching == true && PlayerInRange == false)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, PointB.position, PatrolSpeed); 
}

if(transform.position == PointA.position)
{
    switching = true;
}
else if(transform.position == PointB.position)
{
    switching = false;
}
```

The problem is that the enemy moves super slow until it reaches one of the points, and then just goes crazy fast and starts bouncing between the points. Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks!

Also, I can't make it detect points through collision since I already gave it a big trigger collider in order to detect in the player is in range.

Comment: You probably want to multiply `PatrolSpeed` by `Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: I tried but the same thing happens :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your speed is fixed, so your enemy will always move the same distance. But when reaching a point, you check it with an equality between two position (`transform.position == PointB.position`). That is nearly impossible to achieve, so the enemy go beyond the point, then go backward, then re go forward and surpass the point... etc without stopping.

I would have set a radius (the diameter must be greater than the speed of the guard) and then change direction when the enemy is in it. I remake a bit your code : rename switching by goingToB as it's more explicit. For the translation, use Time.fixedDeltaTime so that the speed of the enemy doesn't depend of the frameRate of your game : [an explication](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/delta-time#6356621cedbc2a001fcf49d7).

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (!goingToB && !PlayerInRange)
    {
        transform.position += (pointA.position-transform.position) * PatrolSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
    else if (goingToB  && !PlayerInRange)
    {
        transform.position += (pointB.position-transform.position) * PatrolSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    }
    
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,PointA.position) <= radius)
    {
        goingToB  = true;
    }
    else if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,PointB.position) <= radius)
    {
        goingToB  = false;
    } 
}
```

I don't know how you did the player detection, but in any case I think that there is some robust method that will solve all the problems you will encounter in further development. I really recommend you the [Unity Learn Tuto on AI](https://learn.unity.com/course/artificial-intelligence-for-beginners?uv=2021.3), they use an example with a guard patrolling and detecting player as you seem to do it. Plus, the tuto is beginner friendly and full of good coding habits

Comment: I would recommend using `Time.deltaTime` instead of `Time.fixedDeltaTime`. It means the same thing inside `FixedUpdate` and if the code is ever moved elsewhere it won't break.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks